# Dynamic group-by in clojure

Tags: clojure

I do have the following data structure in Clojure:

```
(def test-data [{:year 2023
                 :quarter 1
                 :month 1
                 :week 1
                 :date (jt/local-date 2023 1 2)
                 :name "Name1"
                 :value 5}
                {:year 2023
                 :quarter 1
                 :month 1
                 :week 1
                 :date (jt/local-date 2023 1 2)
                 :name "Name2"
                 :value 3}])
```

Now I would like to group this dataset by different keywords rather dynamically (say: by year, week and name or year, month and name or just by name).

I have tried to reach this using some construct like:

```
(defn group-year-week-name [group-keys rows]
  (let [group-keys-set (set group-keys)]
  (map (fn [[grp-key values]] {(keyword (first grp-key)) (first grp-key)
                                ...
                                :value-sums (reduce (+ :value values))
                                :values values
                                })
    (group-by (juxt :week :year) rows))))
```

But this is not working and also not really dynamic (see first, ...).

Any hints on this one?

UPDATE (to provide more input):

The following results are expected with different parameters calling the "dynamic" group-by function.

```
group-year-week
{:year 2023 :month 1 :value-sums 8} 

group-year-name
[{:year 2023 :name "Name1" :value-sums 5 :values [list of values]}
 {:year 2023 :name "Name2" :value-sums 3 :values [list of values}]
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "dynamic" exactly. Also, why do you need anything but the last line in the function with `group-by`? What is it supposed to do?

Comment: can you provide an example expected output?

Answer (score 6):

Do you just mean:

```clj
(defn group-by-keys [group-keys rows]
  (group-by (apply juxt group-keys) rows))
```

Then you can invoke it like this:

```clj
(group-by-keys [:week :year] test-data)
```

This would give the same result as your example.

Comment: Am I able to add the sums of the values as well?

Comment: I adopted the question to make this more clear. 
Your answer is already the first (and for me big) step in the direction :-)

Comment: for the sum of values you could do `(update-vals grouped-structure #(reduce + (map :value %)))`

Answer (score 3):

as you want some kind of an 'sql-like' select + group-by semantics, you could make up some utility like this:

```clj
(defn select [keys & {from :from gr :group-by}]
  (when from
    (let [selectors (map #(if (vector? %) 
                            (conj (pop %) (partial map (peek %)))
                            [% % first]) keys)          
          selection #(into {} (for [[k & fns] selectors] 
                                [k ((apply comp fns) %)]))
          groups (if gr (vals (group-by (apply juxt gr) from)) [from])]
      (map selection groups))))
```

example data (updated for test):

```
(def test-data [{:year 2023
                 :quarter 1
                 :month 1
                 :week 1
                 :name "Name1"
                 :value 5}
                {:year 2023
                 :quarter 2
                 :month 1
                 :week 1
                 :name "Name2"
                 :value 3}
                {:year 2022
                 :quarter 1
                 :month 1
                 :week 2
                 :name "Name3"
                 :value 11}])
```

so, for your case you can do something like this:

```
(select [:year 
         :week 
         [:sum-vals (partial apply +) :value]] 
        :from test-data 
        :group-by [:year :week])

;;=>({:year 2023, :week 1, :sum-vals 8}
;;   {:year 2022, :week 2, :sum-vals 11})
```

you can also do something more interesting:

```
(let [sum (partial apply +)
      maximum (partial apply max)
      joined-with (fn [sep] #(clojure.string/join sep %))]
  (select [:year 
           :week
           [:count-vals count :value]
           [:sum-vals sum :value]           
           [:max-val maximum :value]
           [:vals :value]
           [:names (joined-with ", ") :name]
           [:dates set (juxt :quarter :month :week)]]
          :from test-data 
          :group-by [:year :week]))

;;({:year 2023,
;;  :week 1,
;;  :count-vals 2,
;;  :sum-vals 8,
;;  :max-val 5,
;;  :vals (5 3),
;;  :names "Name1, Name2",
;;  :dates #{[1 1 1] [2 1 1]}}
;; {:year 2022,
;;  :week 2,
;;  :count-vals 1,
;;  :sum-vals 11,
;;  :max-val 11,
;;  :vals (11),
;;  :names "Name3",
;;  :dates #{[1 1 2]}})
```

Answer (score 0):

a variation around @leetwinski answers without the neat semantics

```
(def test-data [{:year 2023
                 :quarter 1
                 :month 1
                 :week 1
                 :name "Name1"
                 :value 5}
                {:year 2023
                 :quarter 2
                 :month 1
                 :week 1
                 :name "Name2"
                 :value 3}
                {:year 2022
                 :quarter 1
                 :month 1
                 :week 2
                 :name "Name3"
                 :value 11}])


(defn group
  [key-fn transform-key data]
  (reduce-kv
    (fn [result k v]
      (assoc result
             (transform-key k v) v))
    {}
    (group-by key-fn data)))

(group
  (fn [item]
    (select-keys item [:week :year]))
  (fn [k values]
    (assoc k :sum-vals (apply + (map :value values))))
  test-data)

{{:week 1, :year 2023, :sum-vals 8}
 [{:year 2023, :quarter 1, :month 1, :week 1, :name "Name1", :value 5}
  {:year 2023,
   :quarter 2,
   :month 1,
   :week 1,
   :name "Name2",
   :value 3}],
 {:week 2, :year 2022, :sum-vals 11}
 [{:year 2022,
   :quarter 1,
   :month 1,
   :week 2,
   :name "Name3",
   :value 11}]}
```

This splits the work between two functions, one to create the key, one to enrich it. This is clearly not the most efficient solution, which will depend upon the type of transformation your making on your keys and your data.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to group by multiple keys and then get the result from that group. To group them, you could use:

```clj
(group-by (apply juxt [:key-1 :key-2 :key-n]) test-data)
```

Then in order to get the matching results of a specific combination of values, you can use `get`:

```clj
(->
  (group-by (apply juxt [:key-1 :key-2]) test-data)
  (get [value-of-key-1 value-of-key-2 value-of-key-n]))
```